# Extjs5. d&d tree to grid. remove record with children from tree

Tags: extjs

I need when I drop in grid records with leaf = false - all of its children removed from tree
I use this code on drop grid.

```
drop: function (node, data) {   
  data.records[0].parentNode.removeChild(data.records[0]); 

  var tree = Ext.getCmp(component.treeId); 

  tree.reconfigure();
  }
```

But view is reconfigured with warning :"[W] XTemplate evaluation exception: me.getTreeStore(...) is null" and last child don't removed from tree view. (this is happend in function view.doAdd)

If I look store , last child is removed.(store.sinc() send to the server all removed children)

I tried use data.records[0].drop(false),but result is same.

What do i do wrong?

Comment: Do you use same store for the grid and the tree?

Comment: No. for tree I use tree store(I get from server linear data like this http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#lineardata-tree), for grid i use data.store.